# How to use redlock using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have been working few days to understand the [Redlock](https://github.com/brainix/pottery#redlock-) and I have seen that the performance to lock takes around 1 second which seems abit too much to just lock it in my opinion but I could be wrong.

I have created a small script:

**redis_test.py**

```
import serialized_redis
from pottery import Redlock

redis_connection = serialized_redis.MsgpackSerializedRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)


def lock(argument):
    return Redlock(key=argument, auto_release_time=120 * 1000)
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import random
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread

from loguru import logger

from lib.redis_test import lock, redis_connection


class StopWatch:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self._startTime = time.time()

    def getStartTime(self):
        return self._startTime

    def elapsed(self, prec=3):
        prec = 3 if prec is None or not isinstance(prec, int) else prec
        diff = time.time() - self._startTime
        return self.round(diff, prec)

    def round(self, n, p=0):
        m = 10 ** p
        return math.floor(n * m + 0.5) / m


def algorithm_with_lock(random_number):
    print("Keys inside Redis", redis_connection.keys())
    ourWatch = StopWatch()
    ourWatch.start()
    if not redis_connection.exists(f'redlock:{random_number}'):
        # print("Time taken before redis_connection.exists", ourWatch.elapsed()) -> 0.0 seconds
        with lock(f'{random_number}'):
            print("Time taken before redis_connection.exists", ourWatch.elapsed())  # 1.002 seconds
            time.sleep(5)
            redis_connection.set("Hello_world", random.randint(1, 5))
            return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    while True:
        chosen_number = f"number_{random.randint(1, 3)}"
        response = algorithm_with_lock(chosen_number)

        if response:
            logger.info(f"Yay, finished my job! -> {chosen_number}")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            logger.debug(f"Trying new number! -> {chosen_number}")
            time.sleep(1)


for i in range(1):
    Thread(
        target=main,
    ).start()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Issue with that is that it takes too long to actually lock a redis key which ends up that multiple threads can try to lock the same key which ends up being stuck in the lock tree. My guess is that it should not take 1 second to actually lock. But I could be wrong and here I am, I wonder what could be the reason of long time locking and if there is a chance im using it incorrectly?